# Zip all files in filepath

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, zip, filepath

How can I make this filepath

```
zip.write (userhome+'\\thefolder\\')
```

zip every single file in "thefolder" for example how could I add a wildcard of sorts to the end like this:

```
zip.write (userhome+'\\thefolder\\*')
```

Answer (score 1):

[shutil.make_archive](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive) does it:

```
shutil.make_archive( base_name =  '/tmp/myBackup.zip',
                     format    =  'zip',
                     root_dir  =  userhome+'\\thefolder\\', 
                     base_dir  =  './' )
```

Comment: How would I add more files or directories to be zipped to this? Adding another after the comma in "root_dir  =  userhome+'\\thefolder\\',userhome+\\theotherfolder\\" doesn't work.